# Sage CRM - It is possible to use workflow for Quote entity?

Tags: sage-crm

As the title says, it is possible?

I have read somewhere that workflow is available to all primary entities (Quotes is a primary entity, right?) but later on, i read that due to the complexity of the Quote entity workflow is not available.

Noneless i found this

[Sage CRM Community](https://community.sagecrm.com/user_community/f/84/t/3235.aspx?pi3243=1)

Which says to change some values in the Custom_SysParams to make it work

Comment: Hey Gianni, are you using the standalone CRM or SageCRM.com?

Comment: standalone CRM, i think. Trial version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, Quotes are Primary Entities.

It's totally possible to add Workflow to them, but not by default. There are no built-in settings for activating Workflow for Quotes or Orders, but there are hidden settings.

First, **do a SQL backup**.

Next, run these three queries in SQL:

```
UPDATE custom_sysparams SET parm_value = 'Y' WHERE parm_name = 'Workflowquotes'
UPDATE custom_sysparams SET parm_value = 'Y' WHERE parm_name = 'Workfloworders'
UPDATE custom_sysparams SET parm_value = 'Y' WHERE parm_name = 'AllowWorkflowForQA'
```

This will activate Workflow for Quotes and Orders. However, it won't take affect until you have done an IISReset.

After the IISReset, log in to CRM and go to:

```
Administration -> Advanced Customisation -> Workflow
```

Create a new Workflow (don't enable it yet).
Add a rule and make sure you select "Quote" as the table for the rule or select a Quote View. Enable the rule, then save it.

Add it to the Workflow and activate the Workflow.

Create a new Quote and you should see the Workflow rules appear.

**N.B.** You will not see Workflow rules for existing quotes. Workflows only get linked when a new record is created.